# undoing damage from wrong /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: apt-get, package-managers

I had the wrong ubuntu version listed in /etc/apt/sources.list some (it listed precise instead of trusty) which I only discovered after a full day of workarounds for packages that wouldn't install automatically. Now everything is back to speed except for a few remaining troublemakers, libglu and libboost

```
root@brain2:/home/jeremy# apt-get install  libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev
Reading package lists... Done
libglu1-mesa is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
libglu1-mesa-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be    installed or libgl-dev
```

I've tried the usual drill of

```
apt-get -f install
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get clean
apt-get update
apt-get upgrate
```

but they do not avail me.  Any advisory information appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to tell if you fixed your /apt/etc/sources.list without knowing what your ubuntu version is and the contents of the file.  Here are some commands that may help you troubleshoot, or someone with more experience than me might comment on:

```
apt-cache policy <package>

rmadison <package>
```

The apt-cache policy command will essentially tell you, from your /etc/apt/services.list file, what versions of that package apt sees as available to download.  Official documentation is available here:
https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.apt-cache.html

The rmadison command performs a similar function but with a key difference.  Instead of looking at what you have in /etc/apt/services.list, it queries Debian archives to see what versions of the package are available.  The Debian man page on rmadison is here:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/rmadison.1.html

If the results from apt-cache policy differs from rmadison, it may indicate that you haven't correctly told apt what versions it should be looking for.

Comment: thanks . if i hadn't alreadywiped the machine and reinstalled ubuntu14.04 I'd have given this a shot.